# Find the unique elements in the second list by using a merge operation from mergesort in list1 and list2

Tags: python-3.x

How to use mergesort in this two list and return unique elements from list2?

The code that I tried is:

```
def uniquelist(list1, list2):
    result_list = []
    comparisons = 0
    result = []
    i=0
    j=0
    while i < len(list1) and j < len(list2):
        comparisons += 1
        if list1[i] < list2[j]:
            result.append(list1[i])
            i=i+1
        else:
            result.append(list2[j])
            j=j+1
    while i < len(list1):
        result.append(list1[i])
        i=i+1

    while j < len(list2):
        result.append(list2[j])
        j=j+1

    for element in list2:
        if element in result:
            if element not in list1:
                result_list.append(element)
    return result_list, comparisons
```

The expected outputs are below.

list1 = ['apple', 'bat', 'cat', 'girl', 'hat']

list2 = ['dog', 'eat', 'fern', 'girl', 'hat' 'it', 'jake']

expected_output = ['dog', 'eat', 'fern', 'it', 'jake']

expected_comparisons = 91

But the comparisons that I get is only 10.

Comment: Why don't you post some example code of something that you have tried?

Comment: Here you go, this is the code that I tried.

Comment: I think you're supposed to just extend the existing mergesort. Normally, this would put elements from both sorted input lists to the result: `result.append(list1[i])`. If you comment out that line, you're a lot closer to only seeing elements of `list2` in the result. The only thing left to do is to also exclude elements if they have an equal (`==`) counterpart in `list1`. I'll leave that up to you ;)